# Using vb.net to copy a file from Windows XP to Linux

Tags: vb.net, linux, windows-xp, file-copying

I have some simple vb.net code that I use to copy a file between 2 servers.

> IO.File.Copy(fromFileName, toFileName, True)   ' Overwrites existing files

That works fine when both machines are Windows XP.

What would I need to do differently if 1 of the machines happens to be a LINUX box?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a Windows-compatible network share using [Samba](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/) on the Linux machine. This share can be made accessible to Windows using a standard network path.